# Mysterious disappearance of an Index in an Oracle 10g table

Tags: oracle10g, toad

I have a table in an Oracle database.  An Index has mysteriously disappeared.  Is there any way to find out how that happened?  I am using Toad for Oracle Version 9.5.0.31

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can find out after the fact but you can log future DROPs"

```
    CREATE or replace TRIGGER your_name AFTER DROP
      ON your_schema
          pl/sql_block
```

You'll also have to create a logging table and insert into it.